# How to branch my Visual Studio Online (TFS) Solution?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have a fairly complex solution in Visual Studio 2015. It's source controlled using Visual Studio Online with TFS as the source control mechanism.

The structure is as follows:

```
DefaultCollection
    Team Project Root
        |
        ----Web Apps Folder
              |
              ----Web Application 1
                    |
                    ----WebApplication1.csproj
              |
              ----Web Service 1
              |
              ----Web Service 2
        |
        ----Winforms Folder
              |
              ----Winforms App 1
              |
              ----Winforms App 2
        |
        ----Common Files Folder
        MySolution.sln
```

MySolution.sln is in the Team Project Root, and the solution contains all the various applications within it which are a mixture of web apps, web services and Windows applications.

The problem I have is that I am new to branching and I want to branch the entire solution, but I think that the way my SLN file is in the root will make this difficult?

What I need is to have Web Application 1 branched, and I understand I can branch Web Application 1. But in order to run it I would need to create a new solution file to contain it which would mess things up.

Is there a way I can Branch the entire solution from this scenario, or will I have to try to re-structure things somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would Create a new Folder at Team Project Root called `Main` (TFS Convention, SVN it's trunk, git it's master).

Then move all the items in the Team Project Root into that `Main` folder.

So your structure is now:

```
DefaultCollection
    Team Project Root
        |--Main
          |--Web A pps Folder
            |--stuff     
          |--Winforms Folder
            |--stuff
          |--Common Files Folder
          MySolution.sln
```

Now you can right click on the `Main` folder and from the **Branching and Merging** sub-menu select **Convert to Branch**.

[image]

Now you can right click on `Main` branch, and from the **Branching and Merging** sub-menu select **Branch...**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dave, that sounds like exactly what I was missing when I originally setup the solution. Have tried this on a test project and it looks like it will get me on the right track. Have also taken some time to read the ALM Rangers guide here - http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/ highly recommended material.

Comment: It is worth to mention that in case of moving in TFS all change history will be lost for the given folder at the folder level. Which renders the functionality totally useless.

Answer (score -1):

Your structure should be:

- Team Project Collection Root

  - Team Project A Root

    - Source folder
    - Source folder
  - Team Project B Root

    - Source folder
    - Source folder

You cannot branch at the Team Project Collection or Team Project Root level.  You will have to move the source to a new folder first and then you can branch.

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't think my question was that clear, it seems in VSO I have the following: DefaultCollection->My TFS Repository. from what you're saying my .sln file is in a Team Project Root?

Comment: Have updated my question to better reflect the hierarchy - thanks.

Comment: Actually tried to branch at the team project root and got the error - "The target item ... cannot be under the source item ..."  So that won't work.  You will have to move the code to a new folder and then branch.  Updating answer as well.